# How to rename a Google Sheets tab with a cell's MM/DD value in a different workbook?

Tags: tabs, rename, cell

I need to rename a sheet in a different workbook in google sheets using MM/DD format based on a cell value (L1).
The sheet I copy from will always be named "Previous" and the sheet I wan t to rename will always be named "Copy of Previous".  The following code I have Frankensteined together does make the "Copy of Previous" where I want it, but the renaming happens in a different workbook that I don't want to mess with and when it renames it is not "MM/DD" , but the longest possible date and time format possible.  My brain is fried.

```js
function CloneSheet() {
  // set "thisSheet" to get the spreadsheet by ID
  var thisSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(
    "1DQ9S0RI3owy76F1HTj042Ajeqv0_jWTezO6pbs0H5D0"
  );
  {
    //Copy and paste "Previous" sheet
    var oldSheet = thisSheet.getSheetByName("Previous").copyTo(thisSheet);
  }
  //Sets myValue to the date in the cell I specify
  var myValue = SpreadsheetApp.openById(
    "1DQ9S0RI3owy76F1HTj042Ajeqv0_jWTezO6pbs0H5D0"
  )
    .getRange("Copy of Previous!L1")
    .getValue();

  //********Above here works, but if a change is needed I am fine with whatever********

  //Want tab renamed with "MM/DD" format using data from myValue,  but it renames a tab in different workbook with the longest date format possible
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().renameActiveSheet(myValue);
}
```

I've tried cannibalizing code from people that have similar needs, but everyone uses "active sheets" instead of choosing a specific sheet to rename.  Also I am at a loss on how to make the tab have MM/DD format.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to copy a sheet in another Google Spreadsheet to the same Spreadsheet.
- You want to rename the copied sheet name to the value of `L1` of the source sheet.
- From your script, I guessed that the value of `L1` might be the date object formatted as `MM/dd`.

#### Modification points:

- In this case, `SpreadsheetApp.openById("###")` can be used only one time.
- In your situation, I think that the sheet name can be retrieved from `L1` of `thisSheet.getSheetByName("Previous")`.
- `oldSheet` is not used.
- `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().renameActiveSheet(myValue)` renames the active sheet of the active Spreadsheet.

When these points are reflected in a script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function CloneSheet() {
  var thisSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1DQ9S0RI3owy76F1HTj042Ajeqv0_jWTezO6pbs0H5D0");
  var srcSheet = thisSheet.getSheetByName("Previous");
  var copiedSheet = srcSheet.copyTo(thisSheet);
  var newSheetName = srcSheet.getRange("L1").getDisplayValue();
  copiedSheet.setName(newSheetName);
}
```

- When this script is run, the above goal is achieved.
- If you want to copy `srcSheet` to the active Spreadsheet, please modify it as follows.

  - From

    ```js
    var copiedSheet = srcSheet.copyTo(thisSheet);
    ```
  - To:

    ```js
    var copiedSheet = srcSheet.copyTo(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet());
    ```

#### References:

- [copyTo(spreadsheet) of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet)
- [setName(name) of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setName(String))